# Añadir elementos a un array en PHP

Tags: php, array

Me he atascado en una tarea y a ver si me podéis ayudar.
Estoy haciendo una tienda online donde el carrito de la compra se guarda en una cookie. Lo que pasa es que no consigo añadir productos al array.
Este es el código:

```
<?php

    $carrito[] = '';
    $expira = time() + (60*60*168); // 7 días


    if(!isset($_COOKIE['carrito'])){
        $carrito = array(
            $_POST['producto'], 
            $_POST['modelo'],
            $_POST['precio'], 
            $_POST['cantidad']
        );
        setcookie('carrito', $carrito, $expira);

    }

    if(isset($_COOKIE['carrito'])){
        $carrito = array_push($carrito,
            $_POST['producto'], 
            $_POST['modelo'],
            $_POST['precio'], 
            $_POST['cantidad']
        );

    }

    echo $carrito;

?>
```

He hecho una prueba aparte y no entiendo el resultado.
Con este código, primero me sale bien, pero después me sale el número de elementos que hay en vez de los elementos que hay:

```
    $a[]=('a');
    var_dump($a); //Respuesta: 0=>string 'a' (length=1)

    $a=array_push($a, 'v');
    var_dump($a); // Respuesta: int 2
```

El resultado de este código es un número 5... pero necesito la lista de productos agregador al carrito.
¿Una ayuda por favor?
Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Jamás referencias el carrito de tu variable interna al carrito de la cookie

puedes intentar esto

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['carrito'])){
        $carrito = $_COOKIE['carrito']
        $carrito = array_push($carrito,
            $_POST['producto'], 
            $_POST['modelo'],
            $_POST['precio'], 
            $_POST['cantidad']
        );

    }

    echo $carrito;
```

Comment: No... he hecho esto pero me sigue saliendo igual, me sale un número int pero necesito que salga la lista de elementos que hay guardados, y no encuentro el fallo todavía